# Did the Shinsekai Yori anime cover all of the material in the light novel?

Tags: from-the-new-world

Did the Shinsekai Yori anime cover all of the material in the light novel?

Is there more content past episode 25, and would there be more content to continue the series?

Answer (score 1):

There's no content "past episode 25", per se - the novel<sup>1</sup> ends just where the anime does, with Saki putting Squealer out of his misery, and finishing with a mention of the sign in the academy that reads 「想像力こそが、すべてを変える」 ("Imagination can change everything"). As such, there isn't any content on which one could base a sequel.

However, it isn't quite the case that the anime covered all the material in the novel - clocking in at around 950 pages of dense prose<sup>2</sup>, the novel contained many bits and pieces that didn't make it into the anime.

Some of this is probably because of restrictions on the kinds of content that can be shown on TV - e.g. somewhere around what would be episode 8, Saki witnesses Satoru and Shun having sex, and this is described in the novel in great detail (though not in a salacious way).

Most omissions, though, were probably just because of constraints on the amount of time available to the anime - *Shinsekai Yori* is an incredibly detail-rich story, and translating all that detail to the screen would require far more than just 25 episodes of anime. Remember how we got nearly a full episode of infodump from the false minoshiro in episode 4? That's the cut-down-for-TV version of that scene. In the novel, the false minoshiro speaks for around twice as long.

---

<sup>1</sup> Do note that *Shinsekai Yori* is an actual novel, not a light novel.

<sup>2</sup> In the one-volume edition, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the novel version of "From the new world" is not a light novel.
I think it's a hard SF novel, instead of a light novel.

Yes, the 25 episodes of the anime covered the whole novel.

But there is a new series "New world zero year" that is running in a novel magazine. It has not been turned into a book yet. This series talks about the story before "From the new world".

Comment: Wow, I totally did not know about that. Looks like 「新世界ゼロ年」 _Shinsekai Zero-nen_ has been running (intermittently?) in 「小説現代」 _Shousetsu Gendai_ since August 2011, and follows the story of "Boy A" (the first person to develop psychokinesis). I need to figure out how to get a copy of this...

Comment: Yea, I didn't read zero-nen yet too. by some blogs, it running every month. by the [web site of shousetsu gendai](http://shousetsu-gendai.kodansha.co.jp/latest/201411.html), November's issue have 10 page (636p to 646p). Maybe we need more time to see in a book.